# Функция с возратом указателя. Как?

Tags: c++, c

Есть такая фот функция:

```
void writeProfileFile(char *fileName, String value);
```

Т.к имена файлов состоят из цифр, пишу так:

```
int a = numProfileFile;   //исходное число
int radix = 10;  //система счисления
char buffer[20]; //результат
char *p;  //указатель на результат
p = itoa(a,buffer,radix);

writeProfileFile(p,"value");
```

Всё работает, но это неправильно. Хочу создать функцию которую и буду вызывать, делаю так

```
char *convertIntToChar(int number)
 {
  int a = number;   
  int radix = 10;  
  char buffer[20]; 
  char *p;  
  p = itoa(a,buffer,radix);
  return p;
 }
```

Но при вызове
  writeProfileFile(convertIntToChar(5), String value);

файл не создается. И подозреваю что неправильно сделал функцию convertIntToChar.
Как переделать правильно? Спасибо.

Comment: время жизни буффера закончится после выхова функции, и указатель будет указывать в освободившуюся область памяти, в общем случае это undefined behavior. Вам нужно или передавать буффер на вход в функцию, или выделять память внутри при помощи `new`/`malloc`, а затем освобождать. 
Я бы рекомендовал передавать буффер в функцию, чтобы выделение и освобождение памяти происходило на одном уровне.

Answer (score 6):

Ваша функция возвращает указатель на локальную память. После выхода с функции её значение неопределенно (правда, как выяснилось, некоторые эксперты на собеседованиях спрашивают о том, как использовать это неопределенное значение).

Если Вам доступен с++11 (а сейчас сложно найти компилятор без его поддержки), тогда пишите так

```
std::string filename = std::to_string(5);
writeProfileFile(filename.c_str(), value);
```

Если же по какой то причине он недоступен, напишите эту обёртку сами

```
std::string to_string(int x)
{
   char buf[30];
   itoa(x, buf, 10);
   return std::string(buf);
}
```

P.S. функцию writeProfileFile лучше написать так, что бы она получала std::string, а не `char*` на вход. (а может даже `const std::string&`).

Comment: Дело в том, что это пишеться под ардуино. Там нет поддержки с++11.

Comment: да не может быть https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224746/how-to-use-c11-to-program-the-arduino

Comment: Господа, как это можно сделать без 11 С++. Вот как изменить существующий код?

Comment: я написал все в ответе. почитайте внимательно.

Comment: Есть причины не использовать С++11. В общем как можно решить проблему без 11 Си?

Comment: ещё раз - я в ответе написал функцию, которой не нужен с++11. Но она работает как функция с с++11

Comment: Уже пора на `std::string_view` переходить. И, кстати, `itoa` хоть и есть почти везде, не является стандартной функцией.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте, раз уж полная беда с `string`, так:

```
char *convertIntToChar(int number)
{
     int a = number;   //исходное число
     int radix = 10;  //система счисления
     static char buffer[20]; //результат
     itoa(a,buffer,radix);
     return buffer;
}
```

Только учтите, что следующий вызов этой функции будет портить результат предыдущего, так что не сохраняйте этот указатель, а сразу используйте.

Comment: да нет у него беды с string. А код подобный лучше даже не писать новичкам. (О бессмысленном копировании аргумента я вообще молчу)

Comment: @KoVadim Да я просто не заморачивался с исправлением его кода - просто показал, как обойти возврат указателя на локальный объект...

Comment: @KoVadim а почему так не стоит делать? Вполне валидный код, работать будет. Можно кстати просто глобально было массив объявить.

Comment: К примеру, код будет плохо работать в многопоточном окружении. А об этом ни слова. Плюс, хорошо бы const char возвращать, что бы не было соблазна модифицировать

Comment: @KoVadim *"следующий вызов этой функции будет портить результат предыдущего"* - об этом ни слова?...

Comment: Мне с этим кодом и так все понятно, а вот для других - не факт.

Answer (score -4):

В общем проблема решилась так:

```
char *convertIntToChar(int number)
 {
 int a = number;   //исходное число
 int radix = 10;  //система счисления
 char buffer[20]; //результат
 itoa(a,buffer,radix);
 return buffer;
 }
```

Проблема была в том, что возвращал не то, что надо. Спасибо всем за помощь в решении вопроса.

Comment: "Ваша функция возвращает указатель на локальную память." @KoVadim

Comment: Ну ну... Во-первых, никакой разницы между этим вариантом и исходным нет: после вызова `itoa` `p` указывает на начало `buffer`, т.е. значение вы возвращаете одно и то же в обоих случаях. Так что ничего тут не "решилось" вообще. Во-вторых, возвращаемый указатель по-прежнему указывает "в никуда". В-третьих, в стандартной библиотеке нет никакой функции `itoa`. Зачем вы ее сюда притащили? Вы бы сначала с языком определились.

Comment: Понимаете, нету ни времени ни желания подключать и ковырять С11. Тем более я так понял, просто так он в Ардуино не подключается. А необходимо ковырять конфиги. Вот и всё объяснение.

Comment: @Kamenev_D: Это "объяснение" чего? "Объяснение" возвращения указателя на локальный буфер? Но при чем здесь С11? И при чем здесь вообще С11, если в соседнем ответе речь идет о С++11. Еще раз: с языком определитесь сначала. Почему на вашем вопросе стоит тэг [C++] если вы не хотите использовать С++?

Comment: Хорошо, вот подскажите как в Ардуино использовать возможности С11? Скопировать и вставить не получиться. Что ещё подключить что бы он собрался? Как данный код собрать в Ардуино? А указатель сейчас уберу, раз он так вам глаза мозолит.

Comment: по ссылке, которую я привел раньше, написано, "As of version 1.6.6, the Arduino IDE enables c++11 by default." (то есть, если у Вас среда разработки 1.6.6 и выше - все доступно)

Comment: @Kamenev_D - Вы понимаете смысл фразы про возвращаемый указатель на локальную память?